# How to bring iPad's 5 finger pinch functionality to iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad, multi-touch

On the iPad, a 5 finger pinch will bring you to the home screen. How can we replicate that function on iPhone?

Comment: That's not possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to configure this five finger pinch gesture on an iPhone without jailbreaking it. Currently there are no jailbreaks for iOS 7 (see [jailbrea.kr](http://www.jailbrea.kr) for available jailbreaks).

If the iPhone is a device with a version of iOS that can be jailbroken, then this can be achieved after a jailbreak using `SBSettings` and `Activator` (both installed through the [Cydia](http://cydia.saurik.com/) app store). You can even assign custom gestures, like for example, a three finger pinch or a four finger pinch, for this action.